# kubectl Error: You must be logged in to the server

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I've checked almost all of the answers on here, but nothing has resolved this yet.

When running `kubectl`, I will consistently get `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`.

I have tried editing the config file via `kubectl config --kubeconfig=config view`, but I still receive the same error, even when running `kubectl edit -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth`.

Even when I just try to analyze my clusters and run `aws eks list-clusters`, I receive a different error `An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the ListClusters operation: The security token included in the request is invalid`.

I have completely torn down my clusters on EKS and rebuilding them, but I keep encountering these same errors. This is my first time attempting to use AWS EKS, and I've been trying different things for a few days.

I've set my `aws configure`

```
λ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************Q]: *****
AWS Secret Access Key [****************5]: *****
Default region name [us-west-2]: us-west-2
Default output format [json]: json
```

Even when trying to look at the config map, I receive the same error:

```
λ kubectl describe configmap -n kube-system aws-auth

error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you might find [kubergrunt](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/kubergrunt) helpful. It will configure kubectl to work with EKS.

Comment: but you run "aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <clustername>" no configure your kubeconfig?

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was because of the system time, below solved the issue for me.

```
sudo apt install ntp
service ntp restart
```